# Combinatorics-- Find the number of possibilities to write a given number in a hexadecimal format

Tags: combinatorics

I need to find the number of ways in which one can write a given number in hexadecimal format, where $0$, $1$ and $A$ must appear at least once. Hexadecimal number can have maximum length of the given number.

For example: for $n = 3$, we have 4 possibilities i.e. $10A, 1A0, A01, A10$ (we ignore the leading zero)

Other hexadecimal numbers are allowed. $1A07$ is valid output for $n = 4$.

For $n = 5$, the answer is $10190$. I need to find an answer for $n = 16$.

What is the efficient way to solve this? Is there any algorithm for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the total number of strings.  Subtract those without $0$, those without $1$, and those without $A$.  Use [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to correct for the ones missing two or three of your characters of interest.  You can search the site for many examples.

Comment: so (0, 1, A) = All - (no 0) - (no 1) - (no A) + (0 and 1) + (0 and A) + (1 and A) right?

Comment: No.  The subtractions are fine, but the additions are like (no 0 and no 1)

Comment: ok if I use the formula I get (15*16*16)-(15*15*15)-(14*15*15)-(14*15*15)+(14*14*14)+(14*14*14)+(13*14*14) = 2201, when the answer is 4. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You also need to subtract (no 0, no 1, no A) which you counted, subtracted three times and then added three times, so are counting them once

Comment: Perfect. Thanks